# Defaultdict and lambda function used together

Tags: python, lambda, defaultdict

I am trying to understand some code and I found the following script:

```
defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0))
```

I am not familiar with defaultdict neither with lambda function. I suspect that this is equivalent to initialize a dictionary which values are also a dictionary. Am I wright?

Comment: That's correct, it creates a dict of dict where the inner dict has default value of 0.

Comment: Yes, this creates a dictionary of dictionaries, where the default value for any key in the inner dictionary is `0`.  I'd recommend reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: This initializes and *empty default dict* with the given default factory. Have you read the documentation for defaultdict? Have you read about what a lambda expression does?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but that line in the script should probably be simply `defaultdict(Counter)`.  Building this particular thing with `lambda`s and nested `defaultdict`s is taking the long way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `lambda` expression defines a function in-place.  Arguments go before the `:`, and the result of the function goes after it.  For example:

```
>>> inc = lambda x: x+1
>>> inc(3)
4
>>> add = lambda x, y: x + y
>>> add(19, 23)
42
>>> zero = lambda: 0
>>> zero()
0
```

`defaultdict` is a `dict` that creates a default value any time you access it with a non-existent key.  It does this by calling the function you pass to it.  A common use case is to create a counter by having a defaultdict that automatically creates zero values that can then be incremented:

```
>>> foo = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
>>> foo["bar"]
0
>>> foo["bar"] += 1
>>> foo["bar"]
1
```

Since the function used by a `defaultdict` can be anything, we can nest them by giving an outer dict a function that returns an inner `defaultdict`:

```
>>> foo = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0))
>>> foo["bar"]["baz"]
0
```

Comment: The only addition I'd add is that you rarely see `defaultdict(lambda: 0)`.  Instead, people write `defaultdict(int)` which both tells you that this is a dictionary of ints and uses the fact that `int()` returns 0.  Likewise you'll see `defaultdict(list)` and `defaultdict(dict)` since `list()` and `dict()` create a. new list or dictionary, respectively.

Comment: Instead of `defaultdict(int)` just use `Counter` IMO, but I'm optimizing for explaining OP's specific code rather than explaining better ways to accomplish similar things.  :)  It's not necessary to understand how `int()` works in order to understand how `(lambda: 0)()` works, even if the former is simpler to write.